# Format date on solaris box, date -d is not working

Tags: solaris

I did search a lot for the solution, but not getting proper answer for my query, please help
example, I have a date

> "Wednesday, September 17, 2014 08:45:04 PM EDT"

and I want to convert this to format

> "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p'

on Solaris boxes

Comment: Just to add, this is what iam doing on Linux , date -d '"+output+"' '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p', need similar for Solaris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YYYYMMDDHH date manipulation in shell script in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503892/yyyymmddhh-date-manipulation-in-shell-script-in-unix/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equivalent date from GNU to solaris](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815327/equivalent-date-from-gnu-to-solaris)